# Show that the sequence $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{2-x_n}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I want to show that the sequence defined by $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{2-x_n}$ with $x_0=\frac{2}{3}$ converges. To be honest, I have no idea how to prove that because this sequence is not even monotonic but it is bounded. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The function $x\mapsto\sqrt{2-x}$ is a contraction on $\left]-\infty, 2-\frac14\right]$ with the unique fixed point $x=1$, which is also the limit of your sequence.

Comment: if you take every other term, it's monotonic

Comment: @J. W. Tanner You mean to consider sub sequences $x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n+1}$?

Comment: @Daniil:  yes, that's what I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may help to know what this converges to (if it converges). The limit would have to fulfil
$$ x=\sqrt{2-x},$$
i.e., be a solution of $x^2+x-2=0$. So $x=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt 9}2$, but only the positive solution (that is $1$) makes sense.

So we may try to show that the distance to $1$ decreases. Let $y_n=x_n^2-1$. Then

$$y_{n+1}=x_{n+1}^2-1=(2-x_n)-1=1-x_n=-\frac{y_n}{1+x_n} $$
and as certainly $x_n>0$, we conclude that $|y_{n+1}|<|y_n|$, i.e., $|y_n|$ is strictly decreasing. This also implies that $|y_n|\le |y_0|=\frac59$, so $x_n\ge\sqrt{1-\frac59}=\frac23$, and we find the fetter inequality $$|y_{n+1}|\le \frac{3}{5}|y_n|$$
so that $y_n\to 0$ at least geometrically.

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim_{n\to \infty}{x_n}=l$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}{x_{n+1}}=l$ so if $\{x_n\}$ converges then
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{x_n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}{x_{n+1}}=l \Rightarrow l=\sqrt{2-l} \Rightarrow l=-2 \ or\ 1$$
So $x_n\ge0 $ then $l=1.$
It is easy check $\lim_{n\to \infty}{x_n}=l=1$ by definition.